# SQL Join Return Null Without Duplicates

Tags: sql

I need to join the following tables to create the below desired result:

Table A

| id_1 | id_2 | foo1 | foo2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 456 | abc | def |

Table B

| id_1 | id_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 456 |
| 123 | 789 |

Current Result (duplicates)

| id_1 | id_2 | foo1 | foo2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 456 | adb | def |
| 123 | 789 | abc | def |

The issue is that items foo1=adc and foo2=def do not correspond to id_2=789, and the join is creating duplicate line items for foo1 and foo2 because of the shared id_1.

Ideal Result (null, without duplicates)

| id_1 | id_2 | foo1 | foo2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 456 | adb | def |
| 123 | 789 | null | null |

I've tried iterations of left, inner, and outer joins, to no avail.

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.*, a.foo1, a.foo2
FROM Table A AS a
RIGHT JOIN Table B AS b
ON a.id_1 = b.id_1 AND a.id_2 = b.id_2
```

Comment: When I add the second clause a.id_2 = b.id_2, the resulting table only yields the single line item in which id_2=456. This isn't returning where id_2=789 because it's not in table A seemingly.

Comment: Are you using the `RIGHT JOIN`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the right join. I've also tried switching the order and using LEFT JOIN to no avail.

Comment: Maybe that is an issue related to data type. 
Can you check data type in both tables for id_1 and id_2? 

Maybe you can try cast all IDs as Integer on the JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the and on your join. It should return both

```
SELECT b.*, a.foo1, a.foo2
FROM Table A AS a
RIGHT JOIN Table B AS b
ON a.id_1 = b.id_1
```

`(a.id_2 = b.id_2)` essentially this is saying where a.id_2 is = b.id_2, so it won't return 789 since there is no matching id_2 for that record in table b.